# What happens when I send the land command to my quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter

My first question is: imagine I have a self-made quadcopter and I want it to land. How can I achieve that? Do I have to stop the 4 motors at the same time?

Second question: I use an AR.Drone 2.0. When I send an empty message to the land topic, it lands (measuring the altitude and doing it in a smooth way). What happens when I send the land command? I don't care if you have the documentation about the AR.Drone or another drone. I just want to know how can I achieve the same result. If you have any article or paper or thesis, it will be very welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but the first is the easy way to do it (I suppose it just stops all the motors), and the second is what does the AR.Drone or any other quadcopter when I send the land command (I suppose it doesn't just stops all the motors)

Comment: i would guess that the drone flies to within a few inches of ground and then shuts down the rotors .... that seems to be the most obvious action

Comment: That could be true, but I would need an article or something that tell us that what we think is correct :)

Comment: Because I want to know what happens when I send that command. 50% because I want to know how things work, and 50% because I'm writing my Thesis and I don't want to have anything without knowing exactly how it works

Comment: ok, now it makes sense ... i thought that you are only building a drone, so the response to the land command would be whatever you programmed it to be

Comment: Exactly, but I would need an example or article or something, so I can learn what other people or companies (like Parrot) do.